# How to import the iris dataset in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am currently trying to write a simple machine learning software in Ruby that uses the iris dataset. I'm following a python tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNa99PG8hR8) this one to be exact. I got to the point (at: 1:40) when they start to import the dataset. the code looked like this:

```
from sklearn.datsets import load_iris
```

My question is is there a way that you can import this iris dataset using ruby?

(I don't know if this makes a difference but I'm using the Rumale gem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDatasets for Ruby. This ruby gem allows you to access over 1200 datasets included in R from Ruby. Check the RDatasets Documentation [RDatasets](https://github.com/kojix2/rdatasets)

daru (Data Analysis in Ruby) is a library for storage, analysis, manipulation and visualization of data in Ruby. [Daru Documentation](https://github.com/SciRuby/daru)

Installation
`gem install rdatasets`

```html
require 'rumale'
require 'daru'
require 'rdatasets'

# load datasets
iris = RDatasets.load(:datasets, :iris)
# Daru::DataFrame

# labels # Numo::Int32#shape=[150]
iris_labels = iris['Species'].to_a
encoder = Rumale::Preprocessing::LabelEncoder.new
labels = encoder.fit_transform(iris_labels)
```

Rumale (Ruby machine learning) is a machine learning library in Ruby. Rumale provides machine learning algorithms with interfaces similar to Scikit-Learn in Python. Check the [Rumale Documentation](https://github.com/yoshoku/rumale)